# How to reference elements without assigning Id's?

Tags: javascript, html

So, the following works - but can I replace the references 'img11', 'name11' and 'prof11' with something like 'this' so I don't have to assign id's every time I use this code?

```
<div onclick="changeStored(img11); changeName(name11); changeProf(prof11) ">
    <div  style="float:left">
        <img id="img11" style="max-height:80px;" src="Pictures/Smiley.png">
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
      <p id="name11">Name: Jane Doe</p>
      <p id="prof11">Profession: Something</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I will post the functions just for completeness:

```
function changeStored(img){
    storeOnClick = img.src;
    alert(storeOnClick);
}
function changeName(img){
    name = document.getElementById("name11").innerHTML;
    alert(name);
}
function changeProf(img){
    prof = document.getElementById("prof11").innerHTML;
    alert(prof);
}
```

And no I can't just put the onclick event in the img or p because I need all 3 values to pass back to the functions when the user clicks anywhere in the div.

Comment: I recommend to read http://quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html to get a better understanding of how the DOM works. The are basically two fundamental ways to get references to an element: **Search** (`getElementsById`, `getElementsByTagName`, `querySelectorAll`, etc) and **traversal** from an existing reference (`e.parentNode`, `e.childNodes`, `e.nextSibling`, etc). Of course they can also be combined (e.g. `e.parentNode.getElementsByTagName(...)`). You use the methods that are available to you and which produce the correct results.

Comment: This is a comment because it's not a complete answer. Use `this` instead of the name and then find the proper element by DOM Tree traversal (jQuery shines at stuff like that BTW).

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll read up on traversal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

### html

```
<div class="info">
    <div  style="float:left">
        <img class="myimg" style="max-height:80px;" src="Pictures/Smiley.png">
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
      <p class="myname">Name: Jane Doe</p>
      <p class="myprof">Profession: Something</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### js

```
var _divs = document.querySelectorAll('.info');

function changeAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < _divs.length; i++) {
        var myimg = _divs[i].querySelector('.myimg'),
            myname = _divs[i].querySelector('.myname'),
            myprof = _divs[i].querySelector('.myprof')

        // img
        var storeOnClick = myimg.src;
        alert(storeOnClick);
        // name
        var name = myname.innerHTML;
        alert(name);
        // profession
        var prof = myprof.innerHTML;
        alert(prof);
    }
}
```

#### EDIT

To make this happen on 'click':

```
window.onload = function () {
    var _divs = document.querySelectorAll('.info');
    for (var i = 0; i < _divs.length; i++) {
        _divs[i].addEventListener("click", function () { changeInfo(this) }, false);
    }
}

function changeInfo(el) {
    var myimg = el.querySelector('.myimg'),
        myname = el.querySelector('.myname'),
        myprof = el.querySelector('.myprof')

    // img
    var storeOnClick = myimg.src;
    alert(storeOnClick);
    // name
    var name = myname.innerHTML;
    alert(name);
    // profession
    var prof = myprof.innerHTML;
    alert(prof);

}
```

You could still use the changeAll() if you wanted to do this for all info divs on page..

of course run your js after html has loaded..

Comment: How `changeAll()` could be called ?

Comment: as noted in my answer.. after html has loaded.. either before </body> or on window.onload = function() {}

Comment: OK. I guess original question says that the function will be called when the div is clicked.